# Force a new AddDataDialog to open at a defined directory path

Tags: arcobjects, development

Is there a way to force the AddDataDialog to open to a specific path?  I created a tool that when clicked on a specific feature will open the Add Data dialog, but I need it to open starting at a specified location.  AddDataDialog doesn't have a property analogous to OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GxDialog which the AddDataDialog uses is responsible for storing the last browse location which is opened on next dialog show. However, changing IGxDialog.StartingLocation has only effect if the dialog is actually shown, but you want to show the AddDataDialog instead.

There is one (rather dirty) way, and that's to change registry value named 
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\ArcCatalog\Settings\LastBrowseLocation** to the catalog path you want the AddDataDialog navigate when shown. It is a string entry. For filesystem paths, it's quite straighforward provided that the disk drive is connected in ArcCatalog.

Comment: As it turns out GxDialog works better for my situation. Thanks for the help.