# How can I call a command programmatically and change its defaults?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3

I am quite new to ArcObjects and development, but from what I have researched I can run a command programmatically like so:
[VB]

```
Dim pUID As New UID
Dim pCmdItem As ICommandItem
pUID.Value = "esriArcMapUI.MxFileMenuItem"
pUID.Subtype = 4 'For Save As command
Set pCmdItem = Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(pUID)
pCmdItm.Execute
```

However I want to extend this example so when it executes it changes defaults to always the same folder location and filename. Is this possible with ICommandItem, or do I need another interface?

Comment: Not sure but maybe the save dialog uses [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) did you try setting that before calling Execute?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is similar to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5537/force-a-new-adddatadialog-to-open-at-a-defined-directory-path/5552#5552) (to question [Force a new AddDataDialog to open at a defined directory path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5537/force-a-new-adddatadialog-to-open-at-a-defined-directory-path)). In your case, you would use a different registry key though:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\ArcMap\File Path
```

where `File Path` is the name of a string value pointing to the directory which the Save dialog uses. This method will of course not allow you to specify the actual file name, only the default directory.