# Fetching query from query layer using ArcObjects and C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, query-layer

As shown in the image below, I need to fetch query mentioned within query section of a layer using ArcObjects in C#.

```
            IDocument doc = ArcMap.Application.Document;
            IMxDocument mxDoc = doc as IMxDocument;
            IMap map = mxDoc.FocusMap;
            ILayer mapLayer = map.get_Layer(0);
            IFeatureClass c = (mapLayer as IFeatureLayer).FeatureClass;
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79060/discussion-on-question-by-jay-fetching-query-from-query-layer-using-arcobjects-a).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast the layer to an `IDatalayer2`.
Cast `IDataLayer2.DataSourceName` to `IQueryTableName`
Get the SQL from `IQueryTableName.Query`

Comment: Thanks bro. It worked like a charm. Did you check the answer i posted for a question that we were trying to solve. [link]https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286127/add-in-button-click-open-arccatalog-window-with-list-of-sde-files?noredirect=1#comment458807_286127